# Is the free cancellation within 5 hours still free if using the "Basic Option" with eDreams?

Tags: air-travel, tickets, cancellations, fees-and-charges

I am looking at some ticket on eDreams.  It mentions a free cancellation within 5 hours:

[image]

But it mentions a 25 GBP fee if using the free "Basic Option" in case of any cancellation:

[image]

so I'm confused whether there is any free cancellation within 5 hours still free if using the "Basic Option" with eDreams.

---

'Information' link next to the 'free cancellation [...]':

[image]

Comment: There seems to be an 'information' link close to the 'free cancellation ...' info. What does it say ?

Comment: @audionuma good point, added, nothing interesting.

Comment: Unless eDreams is substantially cheaper, I highly recommend booking directly with an airline. Proceed at your own risk.

Comment: @Hilmar it looked substantially cheaper, but when trying to pay for it, the price suddenly changed and became as expansive as in the airline website... Definitely looks like a crap agent.